# How can I convert a list to a native type to use in my stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, .net-core

I'm trying to pass a list of nodes to my stored procedure, but it doesn't accept list as it isn't a native type. Error message is

> No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...] to a known managed provider native type

Below is my code for C# and the creation scripts for the table type and sp in SQL.
How can I convert a list to a native type to use in my stored procedure?

C# code:

```
public async Task InsertNodesToCodelistAsync(IEnumerable<CodeListNode> nodes, Guid codelistId, string locale)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(dbConfig.ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sp_insert_nodes_to_codelist]", conn)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        Parameters =
        {
            new SqlParameter("@nodes", nodes),
            new SqlParameter("@codelistId", codelistId),
            new SqlParameter("@locale", locale),
        }
    })
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

SQL Creation Script:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.NodesType AS TABLE (
    node_code VARCHAR(255),
    node_parentcode VARCHAR(255),
    node_label VARCHAR(255)
)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insert_nodes_to_codelist]
    @nodes [dbo].[NodesType] readonly,
    @codelistId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @locale VARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN
[...]
```